# Keyword Sensitive Joomla Banners

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-module

I'm trying to enable keyword sensitive in Joomla 3.2 banners. I turned on search by tag in banner's module. I also added the same tag to banner and article but it doesn't seem to work. I read a lot of tutorials (http://community.joomla.org/blogs/community/652-putting-those-pesky-banners-in-their-place.html) but they seem to relate to previous Joomla versions. Eventually banner doesn't show up. Is there any special option which I should turn on to make it work?

Comment: this is working fine, you need to use Meta Keywords instead of tags, also you should set prefix for banner (Use Own Prefix) instead of using global perfix.